# How Can we use ISNULL to all Column Names in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a question

I tried to `google` it but looks like they don't like `*`

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have the following database table:

```
 P_Id   ProductName UnitPrice   UnitsInStock    UnitsOnOrder
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    Jarlsberg   10.45                 16    15
   2    Mascarpone  Null                  23    NULL 
   3    Gorgonzola  15.67                  9    20
```

If I need to replace the `null` with a string I know I do :

```
 SELECT ISNULL(UnitsOnOrder,'No Data') FROM tbl
```

**Questions**

- How can I use `ISNULL()` with multi column names ?
- is it possible to use it with `*`

*Like*

```
SELECT ISNULL(* , 'NO data') FROM tbl
```

I think this will be tricky because of the datatype, you can't pass string to `INT` datatype  so how can I fix this too

**Update**

Okay if i use `ISNULL(`) with a datatype of `int` it will return `0` 
which will be a value to me , how can i pass empty string instead ?

Comment: Nope, you'd have to list each column separately.

Comment: Why do you need to use `*`? Does it not work for you if you have the columns in the field list.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson He doesn't want to wrap every column in the select list with a call to isnull. Trying to cure a symptom, I feel...

Comment: NO i'm working on application from where we collect the SQL quires from the client side and pass this query as string to the server as string the `EXEC` this string , bringing the data to the client side so i'm expecting some one pass * to the SP on the code behinde i identify all my data return as string , i think i should fix this on the code behind

Comment: @MinaGabriel - Doing this when the results are *displayed* is definitely the right approach here..  Data layer should always be abstracted from the presentation layer.

Comment: @MinaGabriel - Sounds like this application is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Beware of passing SQL around.  It's better to build the SQL command on the server side and pass in parameters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use ISNULL multiple times in the same SQL statement for different columns, but you must write it separately for each column:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(ProductName, 'No Data') AS ProductName,
    ISNULL(CAST(UnitPrice AS NVARCHAR), 'No Data') AS UnitPrice, 
    ISNULL(CAST(UnitsInStock AS NVARCHAR), 'No Data') AS UnitsInStock,
    ISNULL(CAST(UnitsOnOrder AS NVARCHAR), 'No Data') AS UnitsOnOrder
FROM tbl
```

If you are building a dynamic SQL query, you could theoretically gather a list of columns in the table and generate a query with ISNULL on each one.  For example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT '

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ISNULL(CAST([' + sc.name + '] AS NVARCHAR), ''No Data'') AS [' + sc.name + '],'
FROM sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.object_id = so.object_id
WHERE so.name = 'tbl'

-- Remove the trailing comma
SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 1) + ' FROM tbl'

EXEC sp_sqlexec @SQL
```

This code has problems when converting some column types like timestamps to an nvarchar, but it illustrates the technique.

Note that if you had another column that should be returned if a value is null, you could use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) expression like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ProductName, P_Id) AS Product...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
ISNULL (COALESCE (column1, column2), 'No Data')
```

You would need to include all column names though, you can't use *

COALESCE returns the first non-null value in its argument list so if they are all null it will return null