# Set 0 instead of null with SQL query in SQL Server (C#)

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I have a table with 500 columns, and many of these are null, also I can not change the database.

It's a shared project.

My problem is null, I would need to put 0 instead of null, but they are obliged to do so in the query.

I tried with:

```
SELECT isnull(mycolumn, 0) 
FROM RGP_RegistrazioneParametri 
WHERE RGP_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = xxxx
```

but without success .... in this instance I should put the name for the column, and since they are 500 columns, I ask ... there is a method to do this automatically on all null?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't think so there is one.

Comment: You could build your query with a text editor that supports regex find/replace which will allow you to copy the name of the column as the alias to the `ISNULL()` for each column.  Combine this with a query to sys.columns to get a list of the columns on that table....

Comment: You can create a `view` of this table which returns all columns. Next time select from that `view`. This way you don't have to write always these conditions.

Comment: I did used regex with notepad++ from creation query script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dynamic sql for it

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + ' = case when ' 
                      + QUOTENAME(col.name) + ' = NULL then 0 else ' 
                      + QUOTENAME(col.name) + ' end'
                      from sys.columns col
                        join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
                        where tab.name = 'RGP_RegistrazioneParametri'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')  

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'update RGP_RegistrazioneParametri 
                              set ' + @cols + '
                              WHERE RGP_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS = xxxx'
select @sql
-- execute (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, but it involves dynamic SQL. Please read [How Can we use ISNULL to all Column Names in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237736/how-can-we-use-isnull-to-all-column-names-in-sql-server-2008)

The accepted answer is very similar to what you need.

Hope it helps.