# Applying a function to dynamic column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to process the results of a dynamic pivot, which results in variable amounts of differently named columns of data. But they do contain data related to each other and are of the same data type. For each of the result columns, I'd like to apply an identical `ISNULL` function. But as I don't know the names of the columns, writing out the operation column by column is not possible.

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8806c1/1). And an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL, C1 INT NULL, C2 INT NULL, C3 INT NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
    (0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (1, 9, NULL, NULL),
    (2, NULL, 8, NULL),
    (3, NULL, NULL, 10),
    (4, 12, 61, NULL),
    (5, 36, NULL, 86),
    (6, NULL, 77, 42),
    (7, 11, 22, 33);

SELECT * FROM T;

 ID |  C1  |  C2  |  C3
----+------+------+-----
 0  | NULL | NULL | NULL
 1  |    9 | NULL | NULL
 2  | NULL |    8 | NULL
 3  | NULL | NULL |   10
 4  |   12 |   61 | NULL
 5  |   36 | NULL |   86
 6  | NULL |   77 |   42
 7  |   11 |   22 |   33
```

An `ISNULL(CN, 0)` would then be applied for each of these columns. How could that be achieved? If that makes any difference, as the pivot query is dynamic, this processing will be performed inside an `EXEC sp_executesql`.

The expected output would then be:

```
 ID |  C1  |  C2  |  C3
----+------+------+-----
 0  |    0 |    0 |    0
 1  |    9 |    0 |    0
 2  |    0 |    8 |    0
 3  |    0 |    0 |   10
 4  |   12 |   61 |    0
 5  |   36 |    0 |   86
 6  |    0 |   77 |   42
 7  |   11 |   22 |   33
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Felix don't understand the question! Do you want to avoid writing `ISNULL` for every column but it should work like `ISNULL`?

Comment: @Felix got that!

Comment: You might need to dynamically generate the query with ISNULL and execute that query. Follow the link [How Can we use ISNULL to all Column Names in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237736/how-can-we-use-isnull-to-all-column-names-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Felix Posted answer please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, `STUFF` and `Dynamic SQL`:

```
-- Get the all columns names from the underlying table
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
INTO #TEMP
FROM [Database_Name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'T' AND COLUMN_NAME != 'ID'

DECLARE @COLUMNS  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Construct a string with ISNULL
SELECT @COLUMNS =  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ',0) ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM #TEMP 
ORDER BY 1 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

-- and use Dynamic SQL
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ID,'+ @COLUMNS +' FROM T'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will satisfy your requirement

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL, C1 INT NULL, C2 INT NULL, C3 INT NULL);
INSERT INTO #T VALUES
    (0, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (1, 9, NULL, NULL),
    (2, NULL, 8, NULL),
    (3, NULL, NULL, 10),
    (4, 12, 61, NULL),
    (5, 36, NULL, 86),
    (6, NULL, 77, 42),
    (7, 11, 22, 33);

--SELECT * FROM #T;


  Declare  @Main varchar(max)=''
--use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for physical table 
        select  @Main += ',isnull('+name+',0) as '+name
         from (select name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =object_id('tempdb..#T')) as spt

        set @Main= 'select '+stuff(@Main ,1,1,'') + ' from #T'
        Exec(@Main)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite like the `STUFF` solutions. And as the pivot query was already dynamic, with the help of Raka and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237826/7089239) on the topic, I generated the list of columns dynamically. I find this code easier to understand.

Assuming the columns generated by `PIVOT` are in `@Columns TABLE (Column VARCHAR)` or similar:

```
DECLARE @Isnull NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Isnull = ISNULL(@Isnull + ', ', '') + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([Column]) + ', 0)'
FROM Columns

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT ' + @Isnull + 'FROM whatever PIVOT things'
```