# Join results of a dynamic `sp_executesql` by row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to join the results of a dynamic pivot to another table (building on my [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592805/applying-a-function-to-dynamic-column-names) on the matter). The column names are dynamic, so not known beforehand, and the result cannot be read into a table variable or such.

For example, a pivot could produce a result like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Query -- INTO @Result

ID | R1 | R2
---+----+----
 1 | 50 |  3
 2 |  9 |  7
 3 | 38 | 21
```

Which I would like to combine with other columns of data:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Result r
JOIN Table t
ON r.ID = t.ID

ID | R1 | R2 | T1
---+----+----+----
 1 | 50 |  3 | 40
 2 |  9 |  7 |  1
 3 | 38 | 21 | 12
```

Are these kinds of queries even possible with SQL Server? To be fair, the column names are not *fully* unknown, they are passed to the dynamic query in a list like `[R1],[R2]...`

---

Here's something to play with. This produces the two example result sets separately.

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(MAX) = '[R1],[R2]';
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX);
SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 50, 3), (2, 9, 7), (3, 38, 21)) AS X(ID, R1, R2)';

DECLARE @Table table (ID int unique not null, T1 int null)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, T1) VALUES
(1, 40), (2, 1), (3, 12);

SELECT @Columns;
EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
SELECT * FROM @Table;
```

Comment: Such a query is only possible with additional dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you have to build a dynamic pivot and then join those results dynamically to some other dynamically generated table it might be way past time to look closely at your system. This sounds like the design phase went the wrong direction and now everything keeps building off of a less than ideal design.

Comment: @SeanLange Appreciate it mate, and I do understand it might raise some concern, but this is not the case.

Comment: OK so what is the question here? You want to join the dynamic results to another table. Is there some column you want to join to in this other table? Do you join each of your dynamic columns to this table? I can't figure out what you are asking here at all.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, a set of dynamic columns joined to another set of columns on one common column, namely the ID here.

Comment: So build out some more dynamic sql with a whole mess of joins. If you have 4 dynamic columns then you would need 4 dynamically generated join statements.

Comment: @SeanLange The amount is dynamic too, and I think one join statement is enough, as it is done on only one column... right?

Comment: How would I know? I have no idea what you are trying to do other than join some dynamic result set to a table. I don't know what the join criteria is.

Comment: @SeanLange I'll refer you to my comments above as well as the original post explaining the join criteria and an example result. To my knowledge, joining two tables together requires no more than one join statement.

Comment: Yeah so just like in your example query above, except it would be in the dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange All this commentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the query fully into the dynamic SQL produced a fine solution. Using a routine like below or similar, however one defines the table to be used in the join, the column names can then be passed in.

```
DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(MAX) = '[R1],[R2]';
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @Query = N'
DECLARE @Table table (ID int unique not null, T1 int null)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, T1) VALUES
(1, 40), (2, 1), (3, 12);

SELECT X.ID, t.T1, ' + @Columns + '
FROM (VALUES (1, 50, 3), (2, 9, 7), (3, 38, 21)) AS X(ID, R1, R2)
JOIN @Table t
ON t.ID = X.ID
';

EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the result of your sp_executesql query into a temp table and join it afterwards.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * INTO ##tmp FROM MyTable'

SELECT * FROM ##tmp
```

Comment: That's the thing though... I can't write out the field names. But Gordon's suggestion of using more dynamic SQL seems to be the way to go.